# Entity Framework Discriminated Associations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there any way of getting discriminated associations to work in Entity Framework 4? That is, where we have the following tables

```
TableA
  RelatedEntityTypeId
  RelatedEntityTypeKey


TableB (1)
  Id    

TableC (2)
  Id

TableD (3)
  Id
```

and I want to have three associations on the entity for TableA:

```
TableB
TableC
TableD
```

which are defined by the RelatedEntityTypeId and RelatedEntityTypeKey fields...when RelatedEntityTypeId = 1, then the association is to EntityB, when RelatedEntityTypeId = 2, then the association is to EntityC, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have same properties for all three tables (B,C,D) ?

Comment: No...so inheritance is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your purpose of doing this. I have used following approach to solve similer problem.
You can define a base type for all three tables (A,B,C).  And when you want retrieve a object use a generic method for all tables (which returns a base object). And then you can check the type of the returned object to get the A,B,C object.

```
    TableBase
    Id

    TableB (1):TableBase


    TableC (2):TableBase


    TableD (3):TableBase
```

Comment: Inheritance is not an option for this unfortuntately, as the types in question already inherit from a different base type.